# How do I get difference days in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, date

I'm facing a problem that I don't know how to solve.

I would like to get difference of 3 days between 2 values. But when I do a query filter one value, i got results:

```
SELECT
    BeginRange, EndRange,
    DATEDIFF(DAY,InicioRange , FimRange ) as DifferenceDays,
    Code
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         MAX(DataTransacao) OVER (ORDER BY DataTransacao) BeginRange,
         LEAD(DataTransacao) OVER (ORDER BY DataTransacao) EndRange,
         Code
     FROM 
         #Relatorio1    
     WHERE
         Code = '000008480700001') AS C
WHERE  
    c.EndRange > c.BeginRange
    -- AND datediff(day,BeginRange, EndRange) >= 3 
ORDER BY 
    DifferenceDays, Code
```

Results:

```
BeginRange  EndRange    DifferenceDays  Code
-------------------------------------------------------
20170601    20170602    1               000008480700001
20170602    20170605    3               000008480700001
```

But when I run query without filter, I don't get the results above.

```
SELECT
    BeginRange, EndRange,
    DATEDIFF(DAY,InicioRange , FimRange ) as DifferenceDays,
    Code
FROM  
    (SELECT 
         MAX(DataTransacao) OVER (ORDER BY DataTransacao) BeginRange,
         LEAD(DataTransacao) OVER (ORDER BY DataTransacao) EndRange,
         Code
     FROM 
         #Relatorio1) AS C
WHERE  
    c.EndRange > c.BeginRange
    -- AND datediff(day,BeginRange, EndRange) >= 3 
ORDER BY 
    DifferenceDays, Code;
```

Results

NOTHING

What am I doing wrong? I can't get the first result that I got in first query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit hard to follow, but I think you just need `partition by`:

```
SELECT BeginRange, EndRange,
       DATEDIFF(DAY,InicioRange , FimRange ) as DifferenceDays
       Code
FROM (SELECT MAX(DataTransacao) OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY DataTransacao) as BeginRange,
             LEAD(DataTransacao) OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY DataTransacao) as EndRange,
             Code
      FROM #Relatorio1

     ) C
WHERE  c.EndRange > c.BeginRange
 -- AND datediff(day,BeginRange, EndRange) >= 3 
ORDER BY DifferenceDays, Code;
```

Comment: Thanks for all ! 

This is exactly what i looking for .

I really appreciate your help ! 

Thanks for all again !